# How to set product available from DATE

Tags: magento2

I have some product in my shop which can be ordered but they will be available for shipping in few weeks (because they are still in factory). Is there any way to set the date when the product will arrive from factory and will be ready for shipment?

Comment: do you just want to show information of `available for ship from` ?

Comment: Exactly. But I can't see `available for ship from` option. Is this a native M2 option?

Comment: You can create a custom attribute with date type and show it on list and PDP